# Installing custom plugin on a clean Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install my custom Eclipse plugin, which works perfectly when launched from the manifest file, onto a clean installation of Eclipse. I've installed the necessary dependencies (GEF and Zest) manually using their update sites. However, the plugin still doesn't show up. I googled around a lot and found a site suggesting I open eclipse with -debug -consoleLog and revealed the following:

Edit: here's a screenshot of my entire log: [image: Log]

"PowerPlugin" is my custom plugin.

I've checked, and my plugin specifies these dependencies with a minimum version number, and I have installed Zest 1.3.0, Draw2D 3.7.2, and the GEF "All-In-One" SDK 3.7.2, which should satisfy these dependencies, I believe.

Any clue what's wrong?

Comment: Can you profile the entire log? There is some dependency that GEF (and draw2d) has that's not getting resolved, so GEF is really not getting installed, which is preventing your plugin from being installed.

Comment: ...ummm, that's *provide* the entire log.

Comment: Sorry for slow reply - it's finals for me. I've added a screenshot with the whole log.

Comment: Do you see the draw2d bundle in your installation? That seems to be the one that's missing, though that should come in with the GEF stuff.

Comment: If I try to install Draw2D again, Eclipse tells me it's already installed. Is there anywhere else to check why GEF isn't being resolved? The only thing I notice is that GEF wants Draw2D version 3.7.0, while the installed Draw2D is version 3.7.2, but I don't think this should be that significant.

Comment: Can you print the entire list somewhere, for some reason it's not picking up draw2d, and that's not showing why on your screenshot (why draw2d is not resolved). If you can do a pastebin of the entire output that would be the best.

Comment: Which entire list? The console log? the installed software? Here's everything in the console when I run -debug -consoleLog -clean : http://pastebin.com/ZssP21k3

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using just indigo update site `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo` and installing all required dependencies like gef and zest from there (assuming that you use indigo as a baseline?). This update site (actually it is now called a "software site" or repository) contains all required dependencies and they will be installed if needed.

When you using Help>Install new software... p2 provisioning system is used and it will make sure that all required dependencies are satisfied before it starts installing anything.

[Updated bellow]

The problem then is with a dropin mechanism. I found it very unreliable. Would be much better if you could install your plug-in using the standard p2 mechanism (by using software site aka p2 repository) that is:

1. Please create a feature project.
2. Add your plug-in (plug-ins) to the newly created feature.
3. Export the feature ("Export Wizard" link on feature.xml editor). Choose directory destination and on Options tab make sure that "Generate Metadata Repository" is selected (this will spare you the time to create UpdateSite project although you could do that if you want more flexibility later).
4. In your exported forlder your should have: feature, plugins folders and also artifacts.jar and conten.jar with p2 metadata.
5. In your destination eclipse go to Help>Install New Software... then Add... and Local... and browse to the folder from point 4.
6. You should see the feature to install in the list (if not please deselect "Group items by category") and then follow the wizard to install your featrue.

If you want to install on the same host you are running then you can use "Install Into host Repository" in point 3.

See also:
http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fexport_wizards%2Fexport_features.htm

Comment: GEF and Zest were both installed from the indigo update site. It's only my plugin that was installed via dropin.

Comment: Also in your new feature you could (and should) define dependency on other features your installation will require (like gef, zest in your case) and then p2 automatically will try to install the missing stuff if it can find it on any of avaliable repositories (or report the problem early befor installation if that won't be possible).

Comment: This seems to be working as far as getting Eclipse to realize it's installed my plugin, but there's still a problem with the Draw2D dependency.